# Structure for first order language

Tags: logic

Suppose our first order language has two binary function symbols $f,g$ and a constant symbol $c$. Let the structure $\mu$ be defined as $|\mu|=\{ 0,1,2,3 \}$, $f^{\mu}$ is addition modulo $4$, $g^{\mu}$ is multiplication modulo $4$, and $c^{\mu}=3$. Suppose $s(x)=2, s(y)=3$. What is $\bar{s}(fgxyc)$?

I'm having trouble evaluating it. Because I have

$\bar{s}(fgxyc)=f^{\mu}g^{\mu}(\bar{s}(x),\bar{s}(y), \bar{s}(c))$. Then I don't know how to proceed from here as $g^{\mu}$ is $2$-nary function.

By the way, I am reading 'A Mathematical Introduction to Logic' by Enderton, Chapter $2$, section $2.2$ Truth and Models.

Comment: Perhaps it should be interpreted as $f\big(g(x,y),c\big)$, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Comment: @dtldarek: Thanks. It makes sense now.

Comment: Yes, it is : $\overline s(fgxyc) = f^μ[g^μ(s(x),s(y)),c^μ] = f^μ[g^μ(2,3),3]$.

Comment: It's in so-called [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)